# Understanding printf?

Tags: c

I have seen many question realting that but I still have a problem or misunderstanding of things. The standards says:
section 7.21.6/9 says

> "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.
>   If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.".

```
char c='a';
printf("%d",c); // is this undefined behavior
```

I know that the perfect  format must be `printf("%hhd",c);` or `printf("%c",c);`

but I want to know what happens exactly ?

In which cases the promotion occurs exactly up or down ?

Is it same for `scanf` ?

Comment: Have you compiled it and checked the result? I would like to know the result too :)

Comment: `int` is not always 4 bytes.

Comment: why I don't get `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char’`

Comment: @Meninx, because the default argument promotions take place and that `char` is automatically promoted to `int`.

Comment: "Get" or "don't get"?

Comment: @self it is not "usually" !

Comment: This is not how things work. If it is so in every box YOU USED it doesn't mean that it applies to all box. One day you can use a box with a different architecture and you will find how it will be useful to know such information. ;)

Comment: @self: `char` is **the same as** a byte. And `int` is _usually_ **not 32 bits. Most targets use 16 bit `int`. Both, number of architectures and number of sold deviced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your example is not undefined behaviour. `char` to `int` is one of the *default argument promotions*. From the spec, **6.5.2.2 Function calls**, paragraph 6:

> the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type **`float`** are promoted to **`double`**

The integer promotions are (from **6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**, paragraph 2):

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an **`int`**; otherwise, it is converted to an **`unsigned int`**. These are called the *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

Comment: Will the `char` get promoted to it's ASCII value (`int`)?

Comment: When was the `char` *not* its ascii value? What encoding was it stored in?

Comment: Not necessarily ASCII, if you were on a system with non-ASCII character set, but yes, the numeric value will be preserved.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Go it now!!

Comment: so for short and int they will directly promoted to int and from that int long they need to have their own format specifier otherwise it is undefined behavior?

Comment: That sounds correct, yes.

Comment: In your answer, you imply that [§6.5.2.2 ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) states that the default argument promotions are applied with variadic functions. However, that paragraph only applies to functions **without** a prototype declaration, which according to sentence 4 of that paragraph, always leads to undefined behavior with variadic functions. Therefore, I believe you should have cited paragraph 7 instead, which deals with functions **with** a prototype declaration, and states that the default argument promotions are applied only to the trailing arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Take this one step at a time.  (A C language answer)

1. `'a'` is *character-constant*  (C11 6.4.4.4 1).  "An integer character constant has type `int`."  (§6.4.4.4 10).  Assigning an `int` to `char` *may* not fit, but that compiler knows the value of the constant and knows that value is representable as a `char`.  No warnings, no problem.

   ```
    char c='a';
   ```
2. Code is passing a `char` to a function with `...` and does not prototype the argument, so applying "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments." `C17dr §6.5.2.2 7`, `c` is promoted to an `int` in the usual case where `CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX`..  Otherwise `c` is promoted to an `unsigned`.

   ```
    printf(some_format,c);
   ```
3. `printf()` receives the `int` or `unsigned`.  Given the format specifier `"%d"`, code expects an `int`.  When `c` promoted to `int` passed, all is well defined behavior.

   ```
    printf("%d",c);
   ```

Using `char c; printf("%hhd",c);` is not the perfect format. `char` is best as a character type.  When needing a numeric value of a narrow type, better to use `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

IMO, to print the numeric value of a `char` in a highly portably way:

```
char c = foo();
#if CHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX
   printf("%d",c);
#else
   printf("%u",c);
#endif
```

Comment: In number 2 of your answer, you claim that [§6.5.2.2 ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) states that integer promotions are applied to variadic functions. However, that paragraph only applies to functions without a prototype declaration, which according to sentence 4 of that paragraph, always leads to undefined behavior with variadic functions. Therefore, I believe you should have cited ¶7 instead, which deals with functions with a prototype declaration, and states that the default argument promotions are applied only to the trailing arguments of the variadic function.

Comment: For the reasons stated in my previous comment, number 4 of your answer is also wrong, as ¶6 does not apply. Only ¶7 applies in this case (unless you are using a variadic function without a prototype declaration, which always leads to undefined behavior).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel OK

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to know what happens exactly ?

Promotion to `int`. So it basically works ("could work sometimes", as purists say).

> Is it same for scanf ?

`scanf` works with addresses of variables which is different story. When `scanf` stores value, memory corrupt may (and often will) occur due to different sizes of variables.

Comment: "Could works sometimes?" No. it works always.

Comment: @CarlNorum It doesn't crash but the result might be somewhat strange - e.g. negative value for some symbols.

Comment: How could that be? The promotions are well defined.

Comment: @CarlNorum There is one corner. `char` can be either signed or unsigned. So that's correct that the behavior will be implementation defined.

Comment: @EugeneSh, no there isn't. Regardless of `char`'s signedness it fits into either an `int` or an `unsigned int`. If it needs to be put in an `unsigned int`, you'll get a format mismatch warning (cv `"%d"`) and all bets are off. If it fits in an `int`, as it does on the vast majority of machines, there isn't any confusion to be had.

Comment: If `char` is unsigned and has a value of, say, `-10`, it will be promoted to a signed `int` with value `-10`. If `char` is unsigned, the same "symbol" will get promoted to a positive signed `int` value.

Comment: Just to emphasize: https://ideone.com/gBQY1O

Comment: @CarlNorum "If it needs to be put in an unsigned int, you'll get a format mismatch warning (cv "%d") and all bets are off." is close but misses an exception of C11 §6.5.2.2 6.  Assuming `char c` promotes to `unsigned`: if the _value_ of `c` is representable as an `int`, then `printf("%d",c);` is not a problem, else UB.

Comment: @chux Is there a UB in my example above? But it is demonstrating different behaviors for signed and unsigned `char`s.

Comment: @Eugene `signed char a = -1; printf("%x\n", a;` is UB.

Comment: @chux Really? But ok, doesn't matter (Update: you are right). Forget about the second print. what about the first one?

Comment: @Eugene  `unsigned char b = UCHAR_MAX; printf("%d\n", b);` is tricky.  If `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX` no problem.  Else UB.

Comment: @chux OK, so I take it as a confirmation of my claim that this code behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120454/discussion-between-chux-and-eugene-sh).